# Package linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64 is not configured yet

Tags: linux-kernel, wireguard, linux-headers

I'm running proxmox host 8.0.4 on debian 12 - 6.2.16-10-pve
One of my LXC running debian 12 6.2.16-10-pve, cant do any apt use
If I try to install any package I got this error

```
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.1.0-12-amd64.
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Error! The /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20210219/6.1.0-12-amd64/x86_64/dkms.conf for module wireguard includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch/config.
This indicates that it should not be built.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.1.0-12-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up ccze (0.2.1-7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-amd64:
 linux-headers-amd64 depends on linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64 (= 6.1.52-1); however:
  Package linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64 is not configured yet.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why would you attempt to build the WireGuard module? it's already provided by the Debian 12's kernel (I don't know if that's the case for the 6.2.16-10-pve which is not provided by Debian).

Comment: never said I attempted to build wireguard module

Comment: But that's what is written anyway.

Comment: In a more direct comment: you should uninstall the package wireguard-dkms

Comment: Could you share the exact command (example) that you are invoking? Maybe that could help clear up the wireguarde-related confusion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.